# 8u2 programming with Flip 3.4.5

Tags: arduino, atmega, atmel

I'm attempting to update the firmware on my [Arduino Mega 2560](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560). I'm following [this](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2) tutorial.

However, when I try to use flip, whenever I try to find my device (from USB), it tells me that AtLibUsbDfu.dll cannot be found. I found [this](http://support.atmel.no/bin/customer.exe?=&action=viewKbEntry&id=219) on atmel's support site, but since I can't even connect to my device it doesn't help me (and there's nothing in the Jungo section of my device manager). Has anybody had this problem before? If so, how did you fix it?

/e1
I found the AtLibUsbDfu.dll file in the Flip 3.4.5\bin directory. This directory is on the PATH system variable.

Comment: When you attach the device to the USB port - does it install DFU drivers? If it does not there are 2 things that are possible: 1) you're not booting the device in DFU mode, 2) drivers are not installed. I saw your other question here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23103/reset-8u2-on-arduino-mega-2560 so if you haven't resolved that you didn't go far enough to have problem 2).

Comment: @Mihailo I didn't realize it had to be in DFU mode first, thanks. Post an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: What is flip? Is it an arduino tool clone? Please provide some context here.

Comment: @ConnorWolf http://www.atmel.com/tools/FLIP.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach the device to the USB port - does it install DFU drivers? If it does not there are 2 things that are possible: 1) you're not booting the device in DFU mode, 2) drivers are not installed. I saw your other question here [Reset 8u2 on Arduino Mega 2560](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23103/reset-8u2-on-arduino-mega-2560) so if you haven't resolved that you didn't go far enough to have problem 2).

So - it needs to be in DFU mode first :)