# Reset 8u2 on Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: arduino

Another question along with [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23100/8u2-programming-with-flip-3-4-5) one.

The [guide](https://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2) I've been following says that after you reset the 8u2 by connecting the two pins shown below, the board should be undetectable by the Arduino IDE. I have successfully done so, but the board is still using COM22 as an Arduino Mega in the device manager. This other [guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XT0-c1-OJ8U) I found shows the board becoming a LibUSB-Win32 device. Anyone know what's going on?

[image: Pins to connect]

Comment: Did you solder the 10k resistor in? (mentioned in the previous step in the first link)

Comment: The [Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560) has it built in. `On Rev2 or later boards: there is a resistor that pulling the 8U2/16U2 HWB line to ground, making it easier to put into DFU mode.`

Comment: Ah, I saw it mention a certain revision didn't need it but I wasn't sure which one you had.

Comment: So you have your Mega plugged in, you short circuit those two pins for a second or so and let it go. At that stage, if everything is alright your Windows should start searching/installing drivers and new device under your Computer should appear (where Camera and other stuff appears - at least on Win 7) as ATMEL DFU or something similarly titled. So are you doing all of the mentioned in that order? Btw, doublecheck if you have that resistor soldered in if you didn't purchase the board directly from arduino.cc

Comment: @Jeffrey - The above image is a Rev2 Uno, not a Mega.  The image of the Mega is at http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/ArduinoMega2560_R3_Front_450px.jpg.

Comment: @Mihailo I am doing everything in that order. Windows 7 does search for a new device, but it still finds the Mega, not an ATMEL DFU. I'm 90% sure I bought the board directly from arduino.cc, but I'll try soldering a 10k resistor on the two spots on the back when I get a chance a couple days from now.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I was using that picture to show where the two pins are to reset the 8u2, I know it's not a Mega.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, my mega did not have the 10k resistor built in for whatever reason. Adding the resistor on let it enter DFU mode without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed that, on my UNO R2, if I bridge the two connections shown briefly, the 8U2 resets and enters DFU mode.  Instantly, the logs on my Linux system that it is connected to show that the ACM device (what would be COM22 for you) has been removed, and replaced with a generic USB device.  The `dfu-programmer` command can then communicate with it fine.

The bridging of the connection should be done:

1. while the Arduino is connected to the computer and powered up,
2. briefly, with a bit of wire, resistor leg, screwdriver, tweezers, etc - whatever you have to hand.

Removing power from the Arduino and re-connecting it returns it back to normal operation.

- Incidentally, the UNO R2 has that block of 6 pins populated with a header - makes it easier...